# Know where the Actual Code Broke In an imported function in PHP

Tags: php, include

For instance, I have a simple include file that has a function:

```
function ViewInclude($file){
    require_once $file.'.inc.php';
}
```

And, another file (say index.php) that uses the function:

```
require_once 'inc.php';
ViewInclude('header');
```

When the `require` fails, Warning message is as:

> Warning: require_once(header.inc.php): failed to open stream:
>       No such file or directory in ..../***tests/inc.php on line 4***

Now, let us say, a few other files also include the `inc.php` file. When `require` fails, the error is **at inc.php at some line**.

Is there a way to know the actual file and line number that triggered the error? (I mean the point of include where error was originated. In above case something like: **at index.php at line 62**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
  function ViewInclude($file){
       if (file_exists($file)) {
           include_once($file);
       } else {
           $debug = debug_backtrace()[0];
           echo 'Failed to include file in '.$debug['file'].
                ' at line '.$debug['line'].'<br />';
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function to see the history of how the script got to that point. Use a `try`/`catch` block or [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to catch the error.